# How to restrict access for Django project on Openshift hosting using apache auth

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, openshift

I put to **/var/lib/openshift/userID/app-root/repo/wsgi/.htaccess**:

```
Order Deny,Allow 

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication"
AuthUserFile ${SECURE}/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy Any

Deny from all
```

Create new user and set a password by:

```
htpasswd -c $SECURE/.htpasswd user1
```

And I want to **authorize** on the site, and after I entered login and password, I see the same auth window on page(don't authorize).
And if I press on **cancel button** than I see the page of the site.

**So, How I can set up apache auth for openshift? And if I press on cancel button then I want that nothing to show on page or some text. Project on Django framework.**

Answer (score 0):

You might try just using the basic options first, without the "deny" statements and see if it works.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```